# Does Spring Data Solr support child documents?

Tags: solr, spring-data, solrj, spring-data-solr

I am investigating Spring Data for Solr, to see if the abstractions it adds will be suitable for my needs, and if I should be using it instead of SolrJ.  I have worked through some examples, as well as quite a bit of the documentation, and I'm trying to determine if it is able to support Child Documents.  SolrJ has the methods "getChildDocuments()" and "addChildDocument()", and this hierarchy is also supported via the Block Join Parent/Child Queries (see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers).  Does Spring Data for Solr support anything like this?  The documentation implies that it does (in section 3.4.3), but I haven't been able to figure out how it works.

Comment: would you mind opening a feature request in [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATASOLR) to help shape the requirements as this is currently not directly supported.

Comment: Hey, Christoph.  I will do that.  Also, thank you for the answer.  It didn't seem to be supported, but I was hoping that someone could verify that.

Comment: @ChristophStrobl Hi, here just to ask if in the meanwhile the feature you're talking about has been developed. Thanks :)

Comment: @freedev for the mapping yes. please see [DATASOLR-394](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATASOLR-394). The fix will be included in `2.0.12`, `2.1.5` and `3.0.0.RC1`.